# Dynamically clear eventSources array

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

How to dynamically clear [eventsources](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/eventSources/) array ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this

> .fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', source )

It is found in the docs [here...](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/removeEventSource/)
The only thing to know is when you supply the source array, do not use the quotation marks. Let me know if this is what your looking for.

**EDIT**

The method above shows how to remove one event source at a time and this method, if the filter is omitted, will remove every event on the page regardless of source...

> .fullCalendar( 'removeEvents' [, idOrFilter ] )

Comment: Thanks Juan, removeEventSource is good for removing sources one by one but How to clear all sources at once ?

Comment: Basic Usage docs of Fullcalendar shows how to call methods using this  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('next'); which calls next method on fullcalendar object but how to access/change properties(like eventSources) of the fullcalendar ?

Comment: I just edited my post. Maybe it will work for you. Basically you can use the removeEvents method to remove every event without a source prejudice. Is this what you need?

Comment: Thanks Juan, removeEvents solves my problem now but I just wonder why there is an eventSources array if I cant do anything with it :(

Comment: You can do stuff with an array... You can place any of these objects into each array individually http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/. You can also use the removeEventSource and addEventSource or just events to filter through events using radio buttons or checkboxes or any other type of filtering dropdown that you want. The possibilities are awesome... be creative! Also it is complementary to accept an answer and up vote after one has been given.

Comment: Correction... the above link is for individual event objects that can be saved to a database. This one http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/ is the array objects that can be used accross all events within the array.

Comment: Thanks Juan for your time but you still didnt answer what I asked for but guiding me different options to achieve the same result :)